# How can I get the geographical position of users (even cars or any vehicles) from Here Platform?

Tags: geolocation, position, user-input, here-api, vehicle-routing

I need to get information about **user's position** (or at least the traffic of users in a certain area, people or vehicles). I have to do it with **Here Platform**, but I didn't find where can I get this kind of data from Here, is it even possible?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we do not have an API to get the current position of the device in real time, if you want to get this you can use the [Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API) in JavaScript or one of our HERE SDKs to be able to carry out this functionality.

In the same way, if you want to obtain information based on certain coordinates, you could obtain the name of the place, address, places nearby and the traffic of that place (vehicular traffic) using our **HERE JS API** or one of our **HERE SDK** (*Lite*, *Explore*, **Navigate* [paid]*).

However, if you want to obtain information about people close to you or vehicles in particular, this is not possible.

We invite you to read our documentation about the products listed here in case you dare to use any of them:

- **HERE JS API:** https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.33.0/dev_guide/index.html
- **HERE SDKs:** https://developer.here.com/products/here-sdk